# Is { $ x \in \mathbb R \mid |x - a| > b$} equal to { $ x \in \mathbb R \mid |x - a| < b$}?

Tags: inequality

This is where $a \in \mathbb R$ and $b > 0$.

I found that for both of them, $a \le x \le a$ which means that $x = a$. Am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The sets are disjoint.

Comment: No, the two sets are not equal. Let $a =0$ and $b$ be say $2$ then $| x | < 2 \neq | x | > 2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equal. The first set is the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $x$ is a distance more than $b$ away  from $a$. The second set is the opposite; it is the set of all $x$ such that $x$ is a distance less than $b$ away  from $a$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm confused, though. Why does $|x - a| < b$ not imply that |x - a| <= 0, which would imply that $x - a <= 0$ or $x - a >= 0$? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The number $b$ is a fixed real number that is positive.  Say, $b = 1$. Then $|x - a| < b$ becomes $|x - a| < 1$. This certainly  does not mean that $|x - a| \leq 0$.

Comment: Of course. How would one represent these sets graphically? Would the graphs have to be more than 2-dimensions? Thanks again.

Comment: Use desmos.com; this website lets you graph inequalities. They would be vertical strips in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The first set does not contain $a$, whereas the second does. So they cannot be equal.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are actually disjoint which means they do not have anything in common.

Note that  $$|x-a|<b\implies  a-b<x<a+b $$

While   $$|x-a|>b\implies x<a-b \text { or }   x>a+b $$

The first set is bounded and the second on is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it ok to write that $|x - a| > b = a + b < x < a - b$?

Comment: No it is not. |x - a| > b  = a + b < x < a - b is not true all the time.