# How can you define $x \in [-3, 5]$ using absolute values?

Tags: inequality

I really want to say that $x > -3$ and $x < 5$ and then somehow get that into the form $x + a > -b, x + a <b$, where $a,b \in \mathbb N$, but I have no idea how to do that. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint: use the sort of description that appeared in [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735926/is-x-in-mathbb-r-mid-x-a-b-equal-to-x-in-mathbb-r-mid-x).

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your reply (I hope I'm not cluttering the site with too many simple questions). I would indeed like to put it in the form of {$x \in \mathbb R | |x-a| < b$, where $a,b \in \mathbb N$}, but I just can't seem to find what a and b are. Any particular method?

Comment: Please note that "everyting maths" should be typed in `$`'s. Even simple math lines. For instance note that $x>-3$ looks much nicer than x<-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\vert b-a\vert$ is the distance between $a$ and $b$. So $\vert x-1\vert \leq 4$ are all points that lie no more than a distance of $4$ from $1$. This gives you $[-3,5]$.

I works the other way around as well: $[a,b]$ has length $\vert b-a\vert$. Its midpoint is $\frac {b+a}2$. So $[a,b]$ can also be seen as the set of all point that lie no more than $\frac{\vert b-a\vert}{2}$ from the point $\frac {b+a}2$. Hence we can denote it by $\left\vert x-\frac{b+a}2\right \vert\leq\frac{\vert b-a\vert}2$.

Answer (score 3):

The interval $[-3, 5]$ can be written as $[1 - 4, 1 + 4]$. This means that it is the interval of radius 4 centered at the point 1, so this may be written as $|x - 1| \leq 4$.

Comment: Thank you. How do I actually go about finding the particular values? Is it intuitive, or do you have a thought process you go through?

Comment: See what number the interval is "symmetric" around; this is the number appearing inside the absolute values. Then find the radius of the interval about that point.

Comment: And if there is no number that it's symmetric around, then there's no way of defining the set using absolute values? For example, if I have the interval $]-1, 6[$, my "symmetric" value would then be 2.5, right? So I could describe it as $|x - 2.5| < 3.5$. However, if my interval is of $\mathbb N$, then I couldn't do that? What about if it's semi-open? Thank you.

Comment: @user494405 Your last comment is a whole other question. If you want it answered you shoul post it as such.

Comment: @gebruiker My apologies. I feel as though I'm spamming questions a little too much, and I think I'm pretty certain of the answer, so I won't bother this time.

Comment: @user494405 Don't be shy to ask question (as long a you've made an effort to solve them yourself). I think your comment would make a great question, given ther are some pitfalls when working in $\mathbb N$. The answer, I believe, is not that trivial.

Answer (score 1):

$x>-3 \quad \iff \quad x-1<-4$

and

$x<5 \quad \iff \quad x-1<4$

Answer (score 1):

$a=-\dfrac{b-a}{2}+\dfrac{b+a}{2}$ and $b=\dfrac{b-a}{2}+\dfrac{b+a}{2}$ therefore

$$a\le x\le b\iff-\dfrac{b-a}{2}+\dfrac{b+a}{2}\le x\le\dfrac{b-a}{2}+\dfrac{b+a}{2}\iff\left|x-\dfrac{b+a}{2}\right|\le\dfrac{b-a}{2}$$
For the particular case $(a,b)=(-3,5)$ we have $|x-1|\le 4$

Answer (score 1):

An interval $[a,b]$ can be characterised as the set of points $x$ such that the distance of $x$ to the mid-point $\dfrac{a+b}2$ of the interval is at most the radius ( = half length) of the interval. In formula:
$$\biggl\lvert\mkern1mu x-\frac{a+b}2\mkern1mu\biggr\rvert \le \frac{b-a}2.\quad\text{Here: }\enspace\lvert x-1\rvert\le 4.$$